# Ansible Json Query

Tags: ansible, json

I got an dictionary output as below from one of the Ansible Task
"

```
msg": {
        "vSwitch0": {
            "failback": true,
            "failover_active": [
                "vmnic1",
                "vmnic0"
            ],
            "failover_standby": [],
            "failure_detection": "link_status_only",
            "lb": "loadbalance_srcid",
            "mtu": 1500,
            "notify": true,
            "num_ports": 128,
            "pnics": [
                "vmnic0",
                "vmnic1"
            ],
            "security": [
                false,
                false,
                false
            ],
            "ts": false
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use Json Query by storing the above output in a variable as "all_vswitch_info" and trying to extract pnics list as below,
When I use the below now,

- debug:
  msg: "{{all_vswitch_info| json_query('pnics')}}"

I am getting empty value as

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

Note: I tried with other option as
msg: "{{all_vswitch_info| json_query('[].pnics')}}" and still I got the same result

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

Is there anything missing?
NOTE: This specific output has vSwitch0. Under circumstances, this could be anything such as vswitch23 or vswitch 3 or with some other name. I cannot hardcode the name as vSwitch0 in json_query. However, **pnics** is the attribute name which won't change per target machine.

Comment: Use `ANSIBLE_CALLBACK_RESULT_FORMAT=yaml`. YAML is better readable compared with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct *json_query* would be

```yaml
  pnics: "{{ all_vswitch_info|json_query('*.pnics') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  pnics:
  - - vmnic0
    - vmnic1
```

You can flatten the list either in *json_query*

```yaml
  pnics: "{{ all_vswitch_info|json_query('*.pnics|[]') }}"
```

or using the filter *flatten*

```yaml
  pnics: "{{ all_vswitch_info|json_query('*.pnics')|flatten }}"
```

Both options give

```yaml
  pnics:
  - vmnic0
  - vmnic1
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    all_vswitch_info:
      vSwitch0:
        failback: true
        failover_active:
        - vmnic1
        - vmnic0
        failover_standby: []
        failure_detection: link_status_only
        lb: loadbalance_srcid
        mtu: 1500
        notify: true
        num_ports: 128
        pnics:
        - vmnic0
        - vmnic1
        security:
        - false
        - false
        - false
        ts: false

    pnics: "{{ all_vswitch_info|json_query('*.pnics') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: pnics
```

Comment: Great Vladmir. Thank you. I had deleted my comment updates.